# Xcode 8.0 does not detect iPhone SE

Tags: iphone, xcode

I connect an iPhone 4S (IOS 9.3.5) it detects. iPhone 5S (IOS 10.0.2) it also detects. By the iPhone SE (IOS 10.0.2) does not detect and the weirdest is that it used to work... Also iTunes recognizes the iPhone. But neither Xcode or Unity detect it. And I have tried to add Device through the Window->Devices. Yes, I am using USB cable to connect. Tried different ports and the same cable detects the iPhone 5S . I also used sudo pkill usbmuxd on Terminal. Rebooted Xcode, and the Macbook always the same result. :\

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Does iTunes see the phone ?

Comment: It does. Instantly as I connect it